# Regular expression to parse template blocks in HTML

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have the following block in my HTML file

```
<!-- BEGIN user_details -->
<h1>{firstname} {lastname}</h1>
<!-- FINISH user_details -->
```

`user_details` above is an array that contains data like so:

```
$user_details = array(
    0 => array('firstname' => 'Hercules', 'lastname' => 'Zeus'),
    1 => array('firstname' => 'Jesus', 'lastname' => 'Christ'),
    2 => array('firstname' => 'John', 'lastname' => 'Smith'),
    3 => array('firstname' => 'Goerge', 'lastname' => 'Bush')
);
```

There are other blocks with diferrent BEGIN/FINSIH array names and different {elements} so, I need a regular expression that will go over the entire file and look for blocks like that one and then go over each of the values in it and replace them with actual values…

My final output should be:

```
<!-- user_details -->
<h1>Hercules Zeus</h1>
<h1>Jesus Christ</h1>
<h1>John Smith</h1>
<h1>George Bush</h1>
<!-- /userdetails -->
```

The `<h1>…</h1>` tags are not fixed, in some blocks I use `<li></li>`, etc.

I now have this code:

```
$search_in = file_get_contents('path/to/my/html/file/');
$search_for = "#<!-- BEGIN (.*?) -->(.+?)<!-- FINISH (.*?) -->#si";
if (!preg_match($search_for, $search_in, $return)) {
    return NULL;
}

$return = preg_replace("#<!-- BEGIN (.*?) -->", "", $return[0]);
$return = preg_replace("<!-- FINISH (.*?) -->#si", "", $return);
return var_dump($return);

//Look for anything enclosed in curly brackes like so {something}
    if(!preg_match_all("/{([^}]*)}/", $search_in, $matches)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    //Return all occurrences of {something} in an array for use later
    foreach($matches[0] as $value) {
        $_args[] = $value;
    }
```

But the first one does not `var_dump` any data, only `NULL`, and I know that everything above is valid data. I get these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: firstname in /home/content/v/i/r... on line 96
Notice: Undefined index: lastname in /home/content/v/i/r... on line 96
```

I do not want to use a framework like codeIgniter, cakePHP, Zend, or the like.

Comment: Don't use a regular expression if at all possible. Surely there is an HTML-parsing library with decent support to navigate through elements.

Comment: Also,  user2864740, I custom made my blocks, so I need to know how to do so myself, and I am not interested in DDM, smarty or the likes, their files are too big I just need a couple of functions

Comment: I meant DOM above not DDM

Comment: Your code is quite a mess. You confused `preg_replace` for `str_replace`. You have split the regex and now you have two ill-formed regexes. You have written `$return[0]` instead of just `$return`. You are using return value of [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), but it has no return value.

Comment: Sorry, Palec, those regexes are not appearing together as shown, the second one is called if the first one returned some values

Comment: Each PCRE regex must have delimiters. You use `#` as a delimiter in the first regex and that is OK. But the other do not have a delimiter – they have it just on one side each. Also the modifiers (`si`) should be the same for both. And you didn’t fix the `$return[0]` error either. But never mind, I already posted an answer that should work. Did not test, but it should work nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function expand_template_blocks($matches) {
    $name = $matches[1];
    if (!isset($GLOBALS[$name])) {
        trigger_error("$name block has no input values");
        return "<!-- ERROR: $name -->";
    }
    $values = $GLOBALS[$name];
    $template_body = $matches[2];
    $expanded = '';
    foreach ($values as $item) {
        $expanded .= preg_replace_callback(
            "#{([^}]*)}#",
            function($m) use ($item) {
                // If an unknown key is found, the placeholder is left untouched.
                return isset($item[$m[1]]) ? $item[$m[1]] : $m[0];
            },
            $template_body
        );
    }
    return "<!-- $name -->$expanded<!-- /$name -->";
}
function process_file($path) {
    $source = file_get_contents($path);
    $block_template = '#<!-- BEGIN (.*?) -->(.+?)<!-- FINISH \1 -->#si';
    return preg_replace_callback($block_template, 'expand_template_blocks', $source);
}

echo process_file('path/to/my/html/file/');
```

Each block template match is passed to `expand_template_blocks` and replaced by its output. The block name is used to get a global array of that name. Each item of this array is used as an associative array to instantiate the template – placeholders are replaced with corresponding values from the item. All template instances are concatenated.

This requires PHP 5.3.0 because of [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) use. This could be worked-around using [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php).

Comment: Cool, I'm gonna try it now and will let u know how it worked. But, not sure if I'm just dumb here or missing something, but, where did you get the $matches you passed in the expand_template-blocks function? i.e. function expand_template_blocks($matches)

Comment: @HilkiahMakemo `expand_template_blocks` is used as [callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) in [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) inside `process_file`. The argument is supplied by `preg_replace_callback`. See the linked manual pages.

Comment: Palec, you are the man!!!! This works great!!! I modified a little but it works great. I created a class and used return preg_replace_callback($block_template, 'self::expand_template_blocks', $source);

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like you basically need to match `{firstname}` and `{lastname}` separately, and then insert the values as per your array, right?

If that's the case, that's a really basic regex, perhaps **too basic**...

This is the expression you would use...

`(\{firstname\}).*?(\{lastname\})`

If you needed to specify that they are only ever found within `<h1>` or `<li>` tags:

`<(?:h1|li)[^>]*>(\{firstname\}).*?(\{lastname\})</(?:h1|li)>`

Comment: Thanks Vasili, but the values 'firstname' and 'lastname' are different with each array.. Also, the array 'user_details' is different with each block of BEGIN/FINISH data.

Comment: That brings it outside of the scope of regex. Your code would need to search the entire string/file/page (as opposed to line-by-line) and in that case, you would get several matches, each with 2 capture groups. You might have to iterate over each match/groups as you obtain them, unless there is some better way of doing it that I'm unaware of.